# Flash/AS3 > Font Embed causes positioning error with Chalet Font

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts, embedded-fonts

I'm trying to embed the Chalet font to some dynamic text fields and it is causing the vertical position of the text to jump up above the actual text field. (http://www.tonyjacobson.com/chaletFontProblem.png) Is Chalet a messed up font? (or more likely, Flash is sooo screwed up in handling fonts) This font displays absolutely fine in Photoshop and Illustrator.

Can anyone advise me on how to get this font to display properly in Flash?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh... 
Nevermind... looks like I had some conflicts from re-organizing my fonts. I validated and cleaned up the old references (in OS X font book) and then closed down Flash and restarted it and now things are displaying great.